# `overflow:hidden` not hiding scrollbars in Chrome & IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, overflow

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/YRP7Z/ in different browsers.

I have added `overflow:hidden` to both the `div` anf `iframe` but still, scrollbars are appearing in Chrome & IE7-8. Working fine in FF4.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem in chrome you can simply add the **scrolling="no"** attribute to the iframe :

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color: tan;">
        <div id="DOMWindow" style="">
            <iframe id="DOMWindowIframe" frameborder="0" src="http://www.yahoo.com" scrolling="no">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```